# memcached for php5.6 on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, memcached, magento-1.9

The site I am working on is using Magento 1.9.3.2, they are not really wanting to update that app framework at the moment (although I will be trying to get them to move to something more current).  I pulled a full copy of the site down and got LAMP running on my local machine to be able to work with some API issues it is having.  Site runs natively on php5.6 so I went through the steps to get the repo and install php5.6 on my local.  Trying to set up additional things to speed it up a bit now (e.g. site is working and serving properly).  One of the things I want to use is memcached, but therein is the problem.

php version I am running is php5.6, native php-memcached extension in apt repo is for php7, I can't seem to find version specific.  I went ahead and installed memcached and php-memcached from apt, memcached appears to be working per echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211 but looking at my phpinfo page the extension is not working for php.  Is there a way to get the current php-memcached extension working with the older version of php I have for the site?

Comment: Try `pecl install memcached`, this will grab the latest version of the plugin and compile it for your current version of PHP.

Comment: Check the repository you installed php5.6 from.  Possible they supply a php5.6-memcached extension you can install through apt.